# How can I join tables so as to include results that exactly match values from another table, or do not include results at all?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables. I either need results that are associated with a specific value in the second table, or don't exist there at all. How can I accomplish this?

```
TableA              TableB
id    name          table_a_id    value
----------------    ---------------------
1     alpha         1             1
2     beta          2             0
3     gamma         3             1
4     delta         3             1
5     epsilon
```

Desired output:

All rows from `TableA` where value of `TableB = 0` OR `TableA` has no association with `TableB` at all.

```
2     beta          -- associated with 0 value on TableB
4     delta         -- not in TableB at all
5     epsilon       -- not in TableB at all
```

How can I get these results in one query?

Here's an inefficient way to accomplish this:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA a,TableB b
WHERE
        a.id = b.table_a_id
    AND a.id NOT IN (
            SELECT table_a_id
            FROM TableB
            WHERE value != 0
        );
```

What do you recommend?

Comment: use join for two separate select statements. problem solved.

Comment: How is the relation between the two tables? How many rows in tableB can have the same table_a_id?

Comment: @Frazz, `TableA.id = TableB.table_a_id`. Both tables may have millions of rows. One-to-Many. There can be many rows in TableB with the same table_a_id.

Comment: Ok... master-detail then... but then you need to refine the question. If TableB can have many rows with the same table_a_id... do you want to select on TableA if you can find at least one row in TableB with a 0 value? Or do you need all related rows to have a 0 value. Please edit these details into the question.

Answer (score 1):

I would option for a UNION and recommend to use EXPLAIN to check the performance.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    a.*
FROM
    TableA a
INNER JOIN
    TableB b
ON
    a.id = b.table_a_id
AND
    b.value = 0

UNION ALL   -- There can't be duplicates

SELECT
    a.*
FROM
    TableA a
LEFT JOIN
    TableB b
ON
    a.id = b.table_a_id
WHERE
    b.table_a_id IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.id, a.name
FROM 
    TableA a 
    LEFT JOIN TableB b ON a.id = b.table_a_id
WHERE
    b.value = 0 or Isnull(b.value);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the OPs example sql will return the desired result bc the join will exclude ids 4 and 5. You can use a left join to tableb and check if its id is not null that its value is 0 OR if its null:

```
select * 
from tablea a 
left join tableb b on bi.id = a.id 
where b.value = 0 or b.id is null
```

Note that if value is nullable you do not want to use it for checking the left join. Assuming id is not nullable then if b.id is null then we know there is no id in table b matching the outputted table a id.

Answer (score 0):

The first answer that come to mind is something like this:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM      TableA a
LEFT JOIN TableB b ON a.id = b.table_a_id
WHERE b.table_a_id IS NULL OR b.value = 0
```

It is very similar to JRLambert's but it tests the b.table_a_id for NULL instead of b.value. This is more solid because b.table_id is the JOIN column... it can be NULL only if there is no matching row in TableB. From what you told us b.value could very well be NULLable on its own.

But this only works correctly if TableB can have at most one row with the same table_a_id and value=0. Otherwise the JOIN will show multiple rows for the same TableA row, which doesn't seem to be desired.

In this case, you need to do something different. You could simply add a DISTINCT, but this works only if you are not SELECTing columns from TableB.

Another approach is to use the EXISTS:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
           SELECT b.table_a_id
           FROM TableB b
           WHERE b.table_a_id=a._id)
      OR  EXISTS (
           SELECT b.table_a_id
           FROM TableB b
           WHERE b.table_a_id=a._id AND b.value=0)
```

You could also use a UNION, but with millions of records I would avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it with a `LEFT JOIN` and limit information; during the `ON` section.

```
SELECT a.*, b.* FROM TableA a
LEFT JOIN TableB b ON a.id = b.id AND b.value NOT IN (0)
```

The `LEFT JOIN` will get everything that matches or doesn't match between `a` and `b` (while only getting information, on `b` where the `value`  is not `0`).